# Lightning Web Component is not available in App Builder when deploying from VS code

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am used to of 'The Welkin Suite' editor for official development. I am not frequent user of VS code. Only using VS code for personal use. Yesterday I observed weird issue while deploying LWC component to my playground org.

I did copy paste code(bikeCard component) from trailhead(below link) and it deployed but was not available in AppBuilder.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/push-lightning-web-component-files

I checked the config file and change the version as well but didn't work. Then I deploy same code based from 'The Welkin Suite' and able to see component in App Builder.

Please let me know if anyone faced same issue and have solution. Otherwise I will report bug to VS code.

bikeCard.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>Name: {name}</div>
        <div>Description: {description}</div>
        <lightning-badge label={material}></lightning-badge>
        <lightning-badge label={category}></lightning-badge>
        <div>Price: {price}</div>
        <div><img src={pictureUrl}/></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**bikeCard.js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class BikeCard extends LightningElement {
   name = 'Electra X4';
   description = 'A sweet bike built for comfort.';
   category = 'Mountain';
   material = 'Steel';
   price = '$2,700';
   pictureUrl = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/ebikes/electrax4.jpg';
 }
```

**bikeCard.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- The apiVersion may need to be increased for the current release -->
    <description>Description for Bike</description>
    <masterLabel>bikeCard</masterLabel>
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>

    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Is the component set isExposed as true in the meta XML file?

Comment: Also did you deploy the whole component? I don't use VSCode so don't know the specifics. It is always best to provide the full detail of the files you have since that makes things easier for the community to help you.

Comment: You need to make sure that isExposed is true in the js-meta.xml file, and also that you have a valid target and targetConfig that would allow the component to be exposed in AppBuilder. See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags).

Comment: Update question with code

Comment: @sfdcfox  :Yes, isExposed is true. I mentioned in question that  same code base of bikeCard component  is visible in App Builder once I deployed by 'The Welkin Suite' editor.

Comment: I use VS Code all the time to deploy LWCs, no problem. My meta.xml files have <masterLabel> and <description> tags. Maybe one of them or both are mandatory?

Comment: @Sander De Jong : I have added 'Description' and 'Master Label' in my code base and in question as well. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this "Experimental: Deploy Retrieve" setting enabled in VS Code Salesforce settings you will see this behavior of `isExposed` not being deployed with the component to the org, effectively hiding it.

If you have this setting enabled in VS Code, disable it.

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-core.experimental.deployRetrieve": true
```

There is an issue documented for the bug: https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2302

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Change the name of  targetConfigs/targetConfig/objects/object  in bikeCard.js-meta.xml from Product__c to Product2, then redeploy to org.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A9AjTSAV